# quit multiple python files for one key press

Tags: python, bash

I have 5 python scripts in which all scripts have main function in it. code is for a logging streaming data from 5 devices.basically, codes are like this[not full codes here]:

```
#!/urs/bin/env python

import time
import pexpect

log = open('log.txt', 'w+')
tool = pexpect.spawn(connection)
start = time.time()
while True:
    try:
        tool.expect('Notification handle = .*? \r', timeout=300)
        a = tool.after
        elapsed = time.time() - start
        output = str(elapsed) + " " + a
        log.write(output)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        tool.close()
        log.close()
        pass
```

Questions: 
I have a script that runs 5 scripts at once using bash script below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
python a.py &
python b.py &
```

It's only one terminal windows after launching the script. but I want to see 5 terminals at once when I run the bash script.

questions:

1. how can I quit those 5 scripts at once for a key press? 5 files are in a while loop forever. but I have keyboardinterrupt except in those 5 files.
2. It's only one terminal windows after launching the script. but I want to see 5 terminals at once when I run the bash script.
3. any better solution than running 5 scripts at once? [using pexpect, while loop for streaming data logging from 5 devices]

Environment: Ubuntu 14, python 2.7.6
Thanks a lot

Comment: We really can't tell you if there is "any better solution" unless you tell us more about what those scripts are doing.

Comment: _"how can I quit those 5 scripts at once __for a key press__?"_  What does "a key press" mean to you?  To do something with bash or python, one generally needs to write a command; a single key press is not enough.  Interactively, one can create short cuts but how that is done generally depends on what environment you are in.

Comment: Nothing can done running them in a bash shell script unless you know bash. Run them from an additional Python program, which would have to first catch a keypress, using subprocess.call https://pymotw.com/2/subprocess/index.html#module-subprocess and psutil to kill the new program and all of it's children, or run each program as a multiprocessing process which can then be killed  https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/basics.html#terminating-processes

Answer (score 1):

You can use a signal handler and wait

```
#! /bin/bash

trap 'kill %1 %2 %3 %4 %5' INT

python a.py&
python b.py&
python c.py&
python d.py&
python e.py&

echo "Waiting..."
wait
echo "Done."
```

Comment: can you check my code? how to run "kill %1 ... %5" to stop it and write file correctly without losing data ? what is %1 stands for ?